# Double-click repeating by how many times button pressed

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouselistener

I have a JList which runs code each time the value in the list is double-clicked.  The value is populated when a button is pressed.  My problem is each time I click the button and then double-click the JList value it will repeat the code by however many times the button is pressed.

For example, the first time everything looks great, but if I press the button again to change the JList value, it will execute the code for a double-click twice.  If I press it a third time, it will execute the code three times and so on.  I am new to this so apologies if this is an easy one.  Thanks for any info.  Code is below let me know if more is necessary.

```
public DefaultListModel results(StringBuilder message)
{   

    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    model.addElement(message);
    showOption.setModel(model);

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) 
            {
                int index = showOption.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                Object o = showOption.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                System.out.println("Double-clicked on: " + o.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    showOption.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to create a new `DefaultListModel` and `MouseListener` each time? Did you notice that your code doesn't even rely on anything you keep creating again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding a new `MouseListener` each time `results` is called...

This...

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
model.addElement(message);
showOption.setModel(model);
```

Shows that `showOption` is an existing instance of `JList` (which is good), but then you do...

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    //...
};

showOption.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Which adds ANOTHER `MouseListener` to the `JList`, so the each time this method is called, there will another `MouseListener` added to the `JList`.

Add a single `MouseListener` to the `JList` when you first create it.